# Windows Service: Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller

Tags: c#, windows-services

I searched foe the solution but could not get it.
Here is the code for windows service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Debugger.Launch();
    try {
        AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening();
           
           
            
        // Log an event to indicate successful start.
           
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Successful start.", EventLogEntryType.Information);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception.
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            
            
    }
}
```

Here is the **class AsynchronousSocketListner**

```
 static string constr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=WIN-OTVR1M4I567;Initial Catalog=CresijCam";

    //string test = constr;

    // Thread signal.  
    public static  ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private  AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {

    }
    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1200);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(200);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                 allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  

                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                 allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string me = e.Message;

        }

    }
```

I am getting different Error messages everytime:

> A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the TCPService service.
>
> Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller

I dont know from where is the error that I am getting is coming. I know one thing that service is not run yet. and It is in this method startListening(). I debugged using Debugger.launch(). But I am not getting to a specific line .
I also think this is related to TCP somewhere but nothing for sure.

The same code is in working state for console Project.
I dont know what other code to put here. But please let me know if needed further detail.

Comment: "allDone.WaitOne();" - Why are you using async if you block anyway. If you don't want things to go async, use blocking APIs ... But that's exactly the problem here: You are blocking the OnStart Method. StartListening should be on a separate Thread, completely.

Comment: Please don't edit questions like this after you've already received answers. It was only by looking in the edit history that I could make sense of the fact that there was no threading code in the original, by which I can make sense of TheGeneral's answer. I'd suggest rolling back to version 1, and then possible editing to *add* what you've updated your code to be, but notice that your current title and most of the narrative *don't* match the code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever... I will get it to initial posts...

Comment: Other reasons for the error discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635231/the-service-process-could-not-connect-to-the-service-controller

Answer (score 1):

This simple answer is your `AsynchronousSocketListener` is not Asynchronous or threaded or anything of the sort. Essentially your service *Start* is timing out,  and will never hit

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Successful start.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

Because it is essentially blocking forever

---

This error says it all

> A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a
>   transaction response from the TCPService service.

---

`OnStart` should only start the work. This typically means spawning a new thread to do the actual work. In short, it is expected that `OnStart` completes promptly.

You will need to refactor your code to run your `AsynchronousSocketListener` in a new thread or task

Comment: I Will try this and let you know

Comment: I have added the code for task start. But then also not working. May be I am doing it wrong. Please review. The updation is in the problem above

Comment: @Ushaphulwani are you still getting the same error?

Comment: I am not getting any error... The process is not throwing any exception at all. But no task is done. I tried to pause the debug process in between after waiting for some time  and it said next step to be done is **ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)**. That only means that service is not started yet... Am I right?

Comment: @Ushaphulwani no, maybe you should test this in a console app first, also maybe you should put in some logging and see where you are getting up to. i mean its hard to know whats going on from here.

Comment: There is no information in eventlog also for anything..its like for Eventlog nothing's happened at all.

Comment: console app is working very fine.. there was no issue at all.. Then only I shifted to service.

Comment: @Ushaphulwani yeah no event log seems suspicious, as there should be obvious logging there

Comment: Let me try something else as I understand you can not help me without any strong clue...

Comment: After adding task()... console application is also exited without any error

Comment: @Ushaphulwani put a readline after the tasks starts in the console app, so the app doesnt exit

Comment: I added the read()... The debugger went into StartListening() but It got out after Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);.. It didnt went ahead and didnt waited for another read to close.

Comment: I called the method directly just to check if code has any error.. But without any thread or task its working in console application... Is the problem because of ManualResetEvent thread?

Comment: @Ushaphulwani maybe, its hard to tell, i dont have time to test this at the moment, but tommorrow ill have a look and create a simple project to test this out for you

Comment: thank you so much.... I will wait for you test results and I will try from my side also...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179423/discussion-between-usha-phulwani-and-thegeneral).